# Control more than one button using tags

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 28 buttons in my application. I need to control them in a single function. All I want to do is make all the buttons visible. I gave tags to the buttons. I tried it with a for loop but I couldn't do it how can I solve this problem?

```
(IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender{

UIButton *btnPressed = (UIButton *)sender;

NSUInteger i=btnPressed.tag;

for(i=0; i<29; i++)
{
    btnPressed.hidden=NO;

}
```

}

Comment: Kindly post your code.

Comment: you're setting one single button's hidden=NO for 29 times, instead of setting 29 different buttons' hidden property to NO.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of tags, use an IBOutletCollection. So now you have a *single* NSArray pointing to *all* of the buttons. Now just cycle through that NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single IBAction method, check tag values and then do what you want to do

```
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender{
     UIButton *btnPressed = (UIBUtton *)sender;

    // Check button tags and write code accordingly //
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use IBOutletCollection. see the following link for your answer.

[IBOutletCollection](http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/)
and

[IBOutletCollection (UIbutton)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159567/iboutletcollection-uibutton)

[IBOutletCollection of UIButtons - changing selected state of buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888422/iboutletcollection-of-uibuttons-changing-selected-state-of-buttons)